# Dry repeated methods and routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby/rails and I have this situation with 3 resources which uses comments provided by the acts_as_votable gem. The thing is, I have added the necessary methods and routes in all of the resources, resulting in a complete non-dry aberration.

My routes are:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'home#index'

  get 'home/index', to: 'home#index'

  resources :users

  get 'thinga/tagged/:tag', to: 'thinga#tags', as: 'tagged_thingas'
  get 'thingb/tagged/:tag', to: 'thingb#tags', as: 'tagged_thingbs'

  resources :thinga do
    member do
      get :like
      get :dislike
      get :unvote
    end
  end

  resources :thingb do
    member do
      get :like
      get :dislike
      get :unvote
    end
  end

  resources :thingc, only: [:create, :update, :destroy] do
    member do
      get :like
      get :dislike
      get :unvote
    end
  end

  devise_for :users, path: 'auth',
  :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth_callbacks' }
end
```

In the controllers the repeated code is

```
  def like
    @thinga = Thinga.find(params[:id])
    @thinga.liked_by current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js { render layout: false }
    end
  end

  def dislike
    @thinga = Thinga.find(params[:id])
    @thinga.disliked_by current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js { render layout: false }
    end
  end

  def unvote
    @thinga = Thinga.find(params[:id])
    @thinga.unvote_by current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js { render layout: false }
    end
  end
```

Can someone help me to learn how to dry off this cases please?. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rails routes concerns

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns

And I think you'll be able to do this

```
concern :votable do
  member do
    get :like
    get :dislike
    get :unvote
  end
end

resources :thinga, :thingb, :concerns => :votable
resources :thingc, :concerns => :votable, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
```

For the controllers - Make a `VotablesController` and have the `ThingasController` or `ThingbsController` subclass it.  You can call a before action to set the `@votable` instance variable and have the subclasses set the variable.  The shared methods will be in one place.

```
class VotablesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_votable

  def like
    @votable.liked_by current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js { render layout: false }
    end
  end

  def dislike
    @votable.disliked_by current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js { render layout: false }
    end
  end

  def unvote
    @votable.unvote_by current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js { render layout: false }
    end
  end

end
```

in the subclasses (this is an example for thinga)

```
class ThingasController < VotablesController

  def set_votable
    @votable = Thinga.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby provides a lot of scope for using code to write code (metaprogramming), so you should be able to write a method that will do the job of adding the repeated routes for you. Perhaps the following code will run:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  def create_votes_resources(name, options = {})
    resources name, options do
      member do
        get :like
        get :dislike
        get :unvote
      end
    end
  end

  create_votes_resources :thing_a
  create_votes_resources :thing_b
  create_votes_resources :thing_c, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
end
```

Comment: might want to provide a DRY solution for the controller methods as well. I would probably go with an included module to handle this.